# Specific terms for the tray and the bus-like cart used by vendors in theaters, stadiums, trains, etc

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, british-english

Is there a specific word in English for the bus-like ([sense 2](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bus); [sense 3 on AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bus)) cart and the tray used by vendors to carry their products through the aisles of trains, theaters, stadiums, etc.?

Comment: To be honest, I’ve never heard of a butcher (sense 4)  Where is that in common use?

Comment: @Jim Reportedly in the US.

Comment: Well not in any part of the US that I’ve lived in- and that’s quite varied.  I wonder if it is US from 100 years ago or something.

Comment: I live in upstate New York; have never heard it used like that.

Comment: @Jim http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Butcher

Comment: @Jim ODO also supports that North American origin of "butcher" for "(train/theater) vendor": "(North American informal) A person selling refreshments, newspapers, and other items on a train or in a stadium or theater." http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/butcher

Comment: @Elian- I'm not arguing it doesn't exist. I'm just trying to find an explanation that fits with my understanding of its use (or lack thereof)  and my first thoughts were either it's region-specific or its anachronistic

Comment: I would think that the British would be inclined to call it some sort of a *trolley*, and that term is sometimes used in the US.

Comment: (And I likewise have never, here in the US, heard "butcher" used to mean "roving vendor" or some such.  But I will admit that I've spent very little time on trains, especially those where such a vendor might be present.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A flight attendant is said to push a ***beverage cart***.

A peanut or pretzel (or cigarette) hawker at a stadium is said to carry a ***vending tray***

Maybe you're looking for ***vending cart*** or ***vending tray***. I don't know of any word that encompasses both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I thought there might be a specific word for each, sort of like a low mobile platform on casters used for carrying heavy loads is sometimes called a dolly. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dolly

Comment: In most contexts where it's clear you're talking about a vendor, I bet you could drop the descriptor "vending" without any distortion of meaning. For example, one could say "The flight attendant pushed his cart down the aisle", rather than "The flight attendant pushed his vending cart down the aisle." The latter sounds a bit redundant. In that sense, there is a "specific" word for each, *cart* and *tray*.

Comment: @Silenus flight attendants do have a multitude of carts, however.  A cart-pushing flight attendant might have a cart containing trash, beverages, duty-free goods, or meal trays (whether being distributed or collected).  There are no doubt other options I'm overlooking.  Magazines?

Comment: @phoog- in which case it would be the meal cart or the beverage cart when it needed disambiguating, but when they announce, "please keep your feet and elbows clear of the aisles so the cart can pass by" it doesn't matter what kind it is.

Comment: @phoog Could it be called "vending wagon"? In a restaurant, a wagon is a platform on wheels used for serving beverages or food. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Wagon

Answer (score 2):

On the UK railways, the phrase "trolley service" is used to describe food and drinks sold by an employee walking along the train. The items are sold from a *trolley*. The same term is used for the airline equivalent, hence the dated/sexist "trolley dolly".